# Want to make my angular expression work as link

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, href

```
<a href= "" style="color: #666; ">{{postMessage}}</a>
```

I am getting `{{postMessage}}` as angular expression, and this post
message is in the form of link , for *eg. www.google.com* .
If i don't include `href` then it is displayed as normal text. if I make `href=""` then it takes me to a blank page, which is obvious. Please help me
over the issue that how can I make my angular2 expression work as link
in html.

Comment: And what should happen when you click the link? Why would you want a link when you don't want to navigate?

Comment: i want to navigate to whatever link i am having within my angular2 expression.

Comment: after clicking the link i want to go to that particular link

Comment: `routerLink="postMessage"` use this.

Comment: What's the problem with adding the link to `href="..."`?

Comment: like : <a routerLink="postMessage"> </a>

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer it takes me to a blank page

Comment: Then the link is invalid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<a [href]="postMessage" style="color: #666; ">{{postMessage}}</a>
```